# Mac after upgrade to 10.11: ld: library not found for -lgcc_s

Tags: fortran

Ever since I upgraded to  Mac OS X 10.11, I can no longer compile my
fortran program with ifort: The following error shows up:

ld: library not found for -lgcc_s

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you reinstall Xcode after you upgraded (and make sure to start it once to accept the license)?

Comment: Yes, I did reinstall Xcode and accept the license.